# Use of "equals" or "not equal to" in Japanese in software or math context?

Tags: translation

I am working on a tool that I want to translate to Japanese and wanted to confirm if I am using the correct version and grammar of the words.

When i translated both "is equal to" and "equals" in Google translate I always got `等しい`. Why is the same word used regardless of grammar? Is that correct?

For equals I see so many variations of `等しい`

Comment: Exactly what is the question here? And what is the difference between "is equal to" and "equals" which Google Translate should spot according to you?

Comment: I would have to agree, what is the difference between the two?  The only one I see is that you have added the `to be` verb.  Otherwise the meaning is exactly the same, is it not?

Comment: The difference is the amount of words, grammar, and what would commonly be expected in the context. For example, "is equal to" in Spanish would be "es igual a".

Comment: This is not a duplicate at all, that other question does not answer my question. That deals with things like multiplication. My question very clearly asks a simple question, equals vs not equal to. It's a comparator.

Answer (score 3):

Japanese grammar is very different from English grammar. に等しい is a correct translation for both “equals” and “is equal to.”